# Conditional Entropy

Tags: entropy, supervised-learning

I need help solving the conditional entropy for the questions listed below. The data set is listed below as well. Would the formula for the first question be: 0.67 * 1 + 0.33 * 1 or 0.43 * 1 + 0.57 * 1?

**1. What is the conditional entropy H(Repurposed | Veteran = Yes)?**
  **2. What is H(Repurposed | Veteran)?**

```
(Index)Droid   Base               New         Veteran     Type         Output(Repurposed)
U-2FG          Scarif             No          Yes        Security      Yes
K-919          Scarif             No          Yes        Security      Yes
X-23L          Wobani             Yes         Yes        Security      No
X-24L          Death Star         Yes         No         Security      No
K-2SO          Wobani             No          No         Security      ?
C-PM1          Jedha              No          No         Protocol      No
B-NC5          Death Star         No          Yes        Security      Yes
K-OS4          Death Star         No          No         Security      Yes
K-OS5          Jedha              Yes         No         Security      No
K-OS3          Scarif             No          Yes        Security      Yes
T-101          Wobani             No          No         Protocol      No
T-HX1          Death Star         Yes         Yes        Protocol      No
T-HX3          Wobani             Yes         No         Protocol      No
T-HX8          Jedha              Yes         No         Protocol      No
```